# If we know transaction ID can we check more info about it on the web?

Tags: transactions

Just curious?

I mean are there ways to see that info publicly?

Answer (score 4):

Any blockexplorer on the web allows you to enter a transaction ID.

Caveats:

- Some are notoriously bad and unreliable. Don't depend on the info they show.
- The transaction ID of an unconfirmed transaction may change once it gets confirmed (same transaction, different ID). This is due to malleability.

Answer (score 1):

Pick your poison:
https://www.google.com/#q=bitcoin+block+explorer

All transactions can be viewed by anyone.